# SQL insert into DB using PHP - issue with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a previous line I had where I was calling something back from the database, and insert it instead.

This is the function I have, but I can't get the `INSERT INTO` to work correctly

I've already debugged that: the connection to the DB is working fine, the session var for `user` is set and that the `$avatarID` is present.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    $avatarID = $_POST['avatarID'];
    $avatarID = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['avatarID']));

    // Insert into DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`avatar`) VALUES ('{$avatarID}') WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query === false){
       return false;
    }else{
       return true;
    }
    header('Location: profile.php');
}
```

I think it's an issue with the `$sql` line. I'm not getting any errors other than a simple blankpage/dead screen.

Attempted changing to just the following:

```
// Insert into DB
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`avatar`) VALUES ('{$avatarID}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

*Edit* OK so I realise the mistake I have made, as this should be an UPDATE WHERE not INSERT INTO. But I am still struggling to get the query details correct even when using UPDATE and WHERE. But still no result:

```
<?php session_start();
require 'connect.php';

if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    $avatarID = $_POST['avatarID'];
    $avatarID = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['avatarID']));

    // Insert into DB
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `avatar`='{$avatarID}' WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query === false){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    header('Location: profile.php');

}else{
    header('Location: choose-avatar.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Side note: Please, PHP maintainers, _remove_ mysql_* already, apparently glowing red deprecation messages in the docs don't work :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `avatar`='{$avatarID}' WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

Comment: Yes I just realised this, but even with changing the details I am stilling getting a dead page.

Comment: Because you have always "return" statement before "header"